# Flexbox justify-content property stops working at a media query

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to vertically center my logo and unordered list in my header with flex CSS, which I've succeeded in doing, but now I can't get them to float to the left and right sides of the header. The `float:left` and `float:right` values I had before don't seem to affect the child divs, so I've added

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

to the header to achieve this. It seems to work when the browser is full width, however when my first media query begins at 1080px, I have set my unordered list to disappear and be replaced by a navigation menu icon. For some reason the menu icon refuses to float to the right of the header – does anyone have any idea why?

```css
.header {
width: 75%;
height: 100px;
margin: 0 auto; 
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

img.standard.logo { 
height: 40px;
width: 360px; 
}

.header nav ul{
display:block;
padding:0;
margin-top:12px;
margin-bottom:0px;
list-style:none; 
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 0px) 
and (max-width : 1080px) {


img.standard.logo {
height: 38px;
width: 342px;
}

img.menu.button { 
display:block;
margin-top:3px;
width:35px;
height:35px; 
background-size: 100%;
}

}
```

```html
<header class="header">
   <!-- LOGOS -->
   <a href="#">
   <img class="standard logo" src="http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Logo-2.png">
   <img class="white logo" src="http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Logo_White.png"></a>
   <!-- LOGOS -->
   <img class="menu button" src="http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Menu.png">
   <!-- HEADER NAVIGATION MENU --> 
   <nav class="header-nav">
      <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
         <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-463">
               <a href="#">WORK</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-584"><a href="#">LANDSCAPES</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-473"><a href="#">SEASCAPES</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-478"><a href="#">MACRO</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-477"><a href="#">CITIES</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-475"><a href="#">LONG EXPOSURE</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-480"><a href="#">MISCELLANEOUS</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-10"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-464"><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-923">
               <a href="#">SOCIAL</a>
               <ul class="sub-menu">
                  <li id="menu-item-11"><a target="_blank" href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-924"><a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-item-15"><a target="_blank" href="#">FLICKR</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-14"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: It is better you provide the `header` block code instead of pasting your website URL each time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice – I'm relatively new here and I'm not really sure what a header block code is, could you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `margin-left: auto` to the nav menu icon in the media query.

The reason `justify-content: space-between` isn't working as you expect in the media query is that your flex container – `.header` – despite showing only two flex items (the logo and the nav icon), actually contains three flex items.

The third item is the main navigation menu, which can't be seen because it contains a descendant with `display: none`.

So with `space-between` the container is set up like this:

```
LOGO                                    NAV ICON                                   NAV MENU
```

When the screen is wide enough, the NAV ICON has `display: none`. So `space-between` works as intended: LOGO and NAV MENU align at opposite edges.

But when the media query kicks in at 1080px, the `display: none` switches from NAV ICON to *a descendant* of NAV MENU. So even though NAV MENU disappears, it's still occupying that space, and NAV ICON stays in the middle.

You could either apply the `display: none` to the NAV MENU itself, or use flex `auto` margins to force NAV ICON to the right edge.

Also, the reason your `float: right` and `float: left` don't work is because the `float` property is ignored in a flex container.

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> - `float` and `clear` have no effect on a flex item, and do not take it out-of-flow.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for explaining that so clearly – I'd never have worked that out on my own. I've added - nav.header-nav {display:none;} and it's worked  :)

Comment: Ah - I just realised that nav.header-nav {display:none;} stops the menu appearing when I click the menu icon at the media query. Is there a way around this or am I best using the margin?

Comment: Your logo and your menu icon are both images. You have the logo wrapped in a `<a href= ...>`, but your menu icon is just an image. Not sure what you're doing there, but wrap the icon in an `<a>` as well, or give it some other way to launch the menu, or just use the `auto` margin solution.

Comment: Maybe there's a reason the `display: none` was not applied directly the the `.header-nav`. The loss of clickability on the sibling item seems to support this. Probably better off using `auto` margin.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, the icon doesn't have an <a> as I've got a jquery script to launch the .header nav ul

Comment: Ok I found another solution to this by moving the NAV ICON below the NAV MENU in my header.php file. I guess now the menu is floating between them, but I can't see it so it's not an issue